# Order by two fields - Indexing

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

So I've got a table with all users, and their values. And I want to order them after how much "money" they got. The problem is that they have money in two seperate fields: users.money and users.bank.

So this is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(54) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `money` bigint(54) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10000',
  `bank` bigint(54) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `users_all_money` (`money`,`bank`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=100 ;
```

And this is the query:

```
SELECT id, (money+bank) AS total FROM users FORCE INDEX (users_all_money) ORDER BY total DESC
```

Which works fine, but when I run EXPLAIN it shows "Using filesort", and I'm wondering if there is any way to optimize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to sort by a derived value (one that must be calculated for each row) MySQL can't use the index to help with the ordering.

The only solution that I can see would be to create an additional `total_money` or similar column and as you update `money` or `bank` update that value too. You could do this in your application code or it would be possible to do this in MySQL with triggers too if you wanted.